# No JNI library to link to on android toolchain

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

There seems to be "jni.h" header in the android toolchain but no library to link to.

Can somebody guide me how can I invoke Java functions from C code in my app?

Comment: The header is sufficient, or do you have some compile time error that makes you suspect otherwise? _"Can somebody guide me how can I invoke Java functions from C code in my app?"_ Yes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Android does not export a JNI library. This means that there is no way in the system to call `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` and her ilk from user-space C code. You can create your own JVM, but it will not be the same Java, and won't have access to Android SDK classes and methods.

In Android, a Zigote process is started with a special JVM (Dalvik or ART), and then Java can load your C code (in form of `.so` files), not vice versa.

Your C code can use the standard JNI techniques like `CallVoidMethod()` and her kin to invoke Java methods. Note that Android SDK Java methods often need some 'handles', like `context`, to have their work done; usually, you must rely on some calls from Java to C that will give you these handles.